# Need to print JAVA Heap Usage and reset GC value using PERL/PowerShell Script

Tags: java

I am new JAVA.

We are using one a tool which is using JAVA Heap size.

Recently we are facing "**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**" and tool is geting **HUNG**.

Now I planning to write a script to get the heap size and if excceds a limt i need to clean the GC so the heap usage wll be low again.

Please help me in this.

**Machine OS: Win 2012 Server**

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Two things.

1. If you get an OutOfMemoryError, garbage collection will not help. OutOfMemoryErrors are:

   > Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, **and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector**. OutOfMemoryError objects may be constructed by the virtual machine as if suppression were disabled and/or the stack trace was not writable.` [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)
2. There are a few JMX implementation for Perl. Here is the first [result off Google](http://search.cpan.org/~roland/jmx4perl-0.1/lib/JMX/Jmx4Perl.pm)

However this will not help, because the problem is not what you think it is. The problem is either:

- The program requires more heap space than what is currently available. You need to allocate more Heap space for the JVM.
- The application is leaking memory (well technically objects, but the result is the same). You need to hire better programmers.